# Cómo corregir unsupported major.minor version 52.0 xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estuve instalando el JDK y  SDK y al compilar mi proyecto me salio el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Scott una pregunta que SDK tienes como target definido,  acaso es el 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En los Settings para Xamarin.Android actualiza tu JDK al 1.7.0+, es muy probable que tengas el 1.6 y por eso te salga el error. En tu SDK Manager asegurate tener actualizado Tools. Si sigue saliendo el mensaje, cierra Visual Studio, borra bin y obj y vuelve a abrir :v!

Comment: vaya hombre, por fin tenemos el gusto de tenerte por estos lares, bienvenido hermano :D

Comment: mi JDK es de 1.8.0

Comment: en tu SDK Manager, asegurate que dentro de Tools tienes todo actualizado

Answer (score 1):

Este problema es por causa de un desajuste de la versión de Java. Referido en la [Wikipedia Java Class Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) :

```
J2SE 8 = 52
J2SE 7 = 51
J2SE 6.0 = 50
J2SE 5.0 = 49
JDK 1.4 = 48
JDK 1.3 = 47
JDK 1.2 = 46
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Esta es la referencia, el error que tienes es porque al compilar estás usando un `JDK` mayor y un `JDK` menor en tiempo de ejecución

Para solucionar esto, debes tener el `JDK` y el `JRE` apuntando a la misma versión.

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que los SDK especificados están instalados en realidad, revisa en el `SDK Manager`!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recordando, tuve este problema en Android Studio y la razón es que tenia definido como targetSDK el API 24, al final tuve que regresar a 23.